# Why isn't main() returning any value?

Tags: c

/*I am trying to return the 1st bit of boolean value of 10 using right shift in the cb function.*/

```
#include<stdbool.h>
bool cb(int N,int i){ //`called function`
return ((N>>i)&1)==1;
}
int main(void) { //`main function`                 
cb(10,1);    
return 0;
}
```

//Status:successfully Executed,but no output.

Comment: Where are you checking if something is returned?

Comment: There's no output because you don't call any function that causes output. On top of that, you don't do anything with the value returned by `cb(10,1);`.

Comment: To output something on the console, you have to say that to your program. Do you know how return values and functions are working?

Comment: but cb function has a return statement.

Comment: Do you know what is the meaning of return in c? https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/return

Comment: okay.i got it,i've put the ((N>>i)&1)==1 statement in printf

Comment: By the way your function will return the same value without the comparison. A bitwise `&` with 1 will be 1 if the first bit is 1 and 0 if it is 0.

Comment: You ask about "returning a value" but you mean "output a value". Theses are different things and should not be mixed. In your code `main` does *return* a value but does not *print* anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`main` doesn't magically return the result of another function, you need to return the value also from `main`

```
int main(void)
{
    return cb(10, 1);
}
```

or you can exit the program from your function with a value:

```
bool cb(int N,int i){ //`called function`
    exit(((N>>i)&1)==1 ? EXIT_FAILURE : EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

and check the return in the console:

```
./yourprogram
echo $?
```

But notice that this is considered bad practice, we usualy return `EXIT_FAILURE` only when something went wrong, instead, you can print the result:

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", cb(10, 1));
    return 0;
}
```

Finaly, you can use a debugger

Change your code to

```
Line 6   int res = cb(10, 1);
Line 7   return 0;
```

and start the debugger

```
gdb yourprogram
breakpoint 7 (after the line you want to inspect)
run
print res
```

Comment: i have stored the answer and then used printf statement it worked . But  return cb(10,1);   gave runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

So Here's your program:

```
#include<stdbool.h>

//`called function`
bool cb(int N,int i)
{ 
     return ((N >> i) & 1) ==1;
}

//`main function` 
int main(void) 
{                 
    cb(10,1);    
    return 0;
}
```

Your program is executing - which means that the main() function is returning successfully (a Value of 0).  You also invoke `cb(10,1);` which calls your function declaration above (and returns a boolean: True/False).  But you don't store the value of that function call, nor display the value with a `printf()` or `cout` statement.

You'll need to add more for your program to give you more noticable output.